# when i submit a form, the .php file loads in the browser instead of running

Tags: php, html, browser, local, mamp

I'm trying to teach myself PHP and following along with an excercise from a book..

When i submit the form, the .php file loads in the browser instead of running..

I am testing this locally on a mac

I have mamp installed.
I also have a database, and a table created within that DB..

The domain is: localhost
UN :root
PW: root

The DB is named: aliens_abduction
The table is named: aliens_abduction_table

I've attached a screenshot of:
the html
the php
the result when you click submit.

I'm obviously missing something completely dumb here, but I'm at a dead end.. I can't figure out why the script isn't populating the DB..

Any help would be amazing, thanks

G

[image: report-html]

[image: report-php]

[image: browser-result]

Comment: Make sure Apache/PHP is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odds are that you are loading the HTML file directly from the hard disk into the browser instead of through the server (which needs a URL starting `http://`).

Comment: that sounds like it could be right, but the project is sitting in a directory in 'htdocs' which is where localhost files reside.. or so i thought

Comment: yeah this is the url:
file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/HF-PHP-Training/aliens-2/report.php

Comment: That's the problem then, you're  browsing to the file on disk. Not though the server URL. Goto http://localhost/HF-PHP-Training/aliens-2/report.php

Comment: The file needs to be in htdocs for the server to see it. You then need to ask the server to get you the page, not get it directly without going near the server. `http://localhost/HF-PHP-Training/aliens-2/report.php`

Comment: When i go to localhost, I get an index of directories of a couple of projects I've worked on..

Comment: @h0rhay That's expected, what happens if your browse through these directions to your file or go to: http://localhost/HF-PHP-Training/aliens-2/report.php

Comment: thanks Quentin! what a tool I am! it works fine now.. How do i give you props?